# Sound in Java: Is it okay to use the same AudioInputStream for several Clips?

Tags: java, audio, javasound, clip

Here's a little program I wrote:

```
package learningSound;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    Clip clip1,clip2,clip3;
    AudioInputStream audioIn;

    public Main(){

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Test Sound Clip");
        this.setSize(300, 200);
        this.setVisible(true);

        try{

            URL url1 = this.getClass().getResource("ah.wav");
            audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url1);
            clip1 = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip1.open(audioIn);

            URL url2 = this.getClass().getResource("eh.wav");
            audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url2);
            clip2 = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip2.open(audioIn);

            URL url3 = this.getClass().getResource("ih.wav");
            audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url3);
            clip3 = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip3.open(audioIn);

            clip1.start();
            clip2.start();
            clip3.start();

        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

It works, but I wonder if there's a problem with using the same `AudioInputStream` for several clips. Is this a problem for some reason? Is this the correct way to manage things?

Also, a completely different question but a small one: If I have a button that when clicked, plays a `Clip`. Will the timing of the playing of the clip be 100% accurate? (This is for music-making).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the static method `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream()` you are getting the audio input stream from the given URI, as long as that URI points to an audio. This mean what your doing in your code *isn't actually using the same stream*. In other words, what you are doing is correct.

As for the 'part 2' of the question I'm not sure what you mean by the timing of the clip? Could you expand on that a little?

Comment: I mean that I need the program to be able to play an audio file without any delay. The moment I call clip.start(), I want the clip to play. Any delay longer than a few milliseconds will be a problem.

Comment: Well the best way to figure that out is to implement it and find out

Comment: There will be a latency, arising from multiple causes. There are various things you can do to try and lessen it. Good article on the various issues: http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/p/pod/dod-idx?c=icmc;idno=bbp2372.2007.131 "Real Time, Low Latency Audio Processing in Java".

Answer (score 1):

The Java Sound based [`Clip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html) preloads the data, so it should be fine.  From the Java Docs.

> The `Clip` interface represents a special kind of data line whose audio data can be **loaded prior to playback,** instead of being streamed in real time.
>
> *Because the data is pre-loaded* and has a known length, *you can set a clip to start playing at any position in its audio data.* ..